# Connecting to new SQL Server 2012 database in Coldfusion 11

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, sql-server-2012, coldfusion-11

I have an existing instance of ColdFusion 11 server and SQL Server 2012 on a Windows 7 Ultimate platform.

I have several SQL Server datasources already connected successfully connected using: localhost\SQLEXPRESS, username "sa" and my password. When I try to add a new database in the CF Administrator I get this error:

> Connection verification failed for data source: ocm5
>   java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: [Macromedia][SQLServer
>   JDBC      Driver][SQLServer]Login failed for user 'sa'. The root cause
>   was that: java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException:
>   [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Login failed for user
>   'sa'.

It appears to be a login issue, not a connection issue so I don't think it has to do with source limits on Developer platforms.

Answer (score 1):

In 2012 or beyond you will not be able to us "sa" - and you *should never use it* anyway to set up a datasource. Doing so opens up a huge attack vector directly to your data and your server itself.

You will need to set up a separate username and password and give it DBO permissions to your DB. This will expose *only* your specific database to your CF connection. If you can you should narrow permissions further - do you really need "create" permissions for example?

Comment: This is a localhost platform for building and testing only. As I stated before I have other instances of msSQL 2012 (and mySQL 5.5) running on my local server with CF 11 and they are all using "sa". The problem is I cannot create a new database connection in CF administrator. As far as permissions on my local platform I just use the defaults and have never had a problem.

Comment: That account has *the* highest privileges and should not be used without a very, very, very good reason. It is easy enough to create a new login, as Mark described above. Unless you are doing something really exotic, those permissions should work out of the gate, and you can reduce them from there. Having said all that, it sounds like maybe you forgot to enable Mixed Mode authentication? If so, any sql server login would fail until that mode is enabled.

Comment: Yes - but newer versions of SQL server (starting with 2012) will not allow sa to be used this way. You will need to set up another user. If you are doing local only and you've locked down access to just the 127.0.0.1 IP, then you are free to set up a server admin user - but as a practice it invites mayhem as leigh has said.

Comment: Also - make sure you are using a standard username/password in mixed mode (as Leigh alluded to).

Comment: *newer versions of SQL server (starting with 2012) will not allow sa to be used this way* @MarkAKruger - IIRC, older versions used to just disable it, but folks could still get around it by re-enabling. Out of curiosity, are you saying 2012+ do more than than just that? (I have not tried it and must be using the wrong search terms because a quick search turned up zilch ;-).

Comment: My recollection is that older versions did not disable it Leigh - that newer versions do. You can reenable it but they don't make it easy. I can ask my DBA if you are curious.

Comment: By older versions, I mean like 2005/2008. I could be wrong, but I seem to recall that is when they first started to lock down the "sa" account (long overdue if you ask me).  I was curious whether 2012+ takes more extreme measures. Do not go to any extra trouble, but if your DBA happens to know off the top of their head, I'd love to know the answer.